# Angular7 : detect change of variable in other component

Tags: javascript, angular, components, output, ngx-translate

I have a component named navbar contain a drop down to change language by ngx/translate :

```
<div class="traduction">
        <ul>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="userDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <img style="width:20px; height:20px;"class="img-profile rounded-circle" [src]="translate.currentLang == 'fr' ? '../../../assets/img/fr.png' : '../../../assets/img/ar.png'">
            </a>
            <div class="lang-menu dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in" aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLang('fr')">
                <i class="far fa-flag fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                Français
              </a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeLang('ar')">
                <i class="far fa-flag fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                عربي
              </a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

---

```
constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
    // private socket: Socket
    private socketService: SocketIOService
  ) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
    translate.use('fr');
}

  changeLang(val) {
    this.translate.use(val)
    this.currentlng.emit(val)

  }
```

I want to detect the current language change varible (val) and send it to other component, should I use @Output decorator and eventEmitor or some thing else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngx-translate` has a service that you can inject in any component you want.

This service has this `onLangChange` method which is Observable you can subscribe to and get the current language change wherever needed:

```
onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
  // do something
});
```

Checkout their docs:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Answer (score 0):

I always put the link to this material, you'll see how to communicate between components https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

You can share data via Input, via ViewChild, via Output() and EventEmitter and the last one - sharing data between unrelated components with a Service.

In your case, you can use a singleton to hold the state, and inject it everywhere you need it to read or change the state (in your case change the language). https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service

Hope that will help!